# Execute FOR loop over ssh

Tags: unix, ksh, solaris-10

I am trying to execute this code on several Solaris 10 remote boxes over ssh. I am reading some connection information from the local file ipa.txt:

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read hostn sid; do

   v_sid=$sid;
   ssh utest@$hostn << EOF

   for D in $(df -k |grep ora | grep -i $v_sid | awk '{print $6}')
   do
       printf "$(df -h $D |tail -1|awk '{print "FS:", $6, " usage:", $5"%"}')\n"
   done

EOF

done < ipa.txt
```

If I only execute the **FOR** loop directly into the terminal, it works. But If I put the whole script into a .ksh file and I execute that one, I receive the following error at line 3 (the line where is **do**, next line after FOR statement).

```
ksh[2]: syntax error at line 3 : `newline or ;' unexpected
```

There is a problem with the **FOR** loop but I don't understand where it is.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: You are missing the closing `)` in the command substitution whose output you are iterating over.

Comment: @chepner sorry, that was a typo, but the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command substitution is expanded *before* `ssh` reads from the here document. If that pipeline is empty, the remote shell sees

```
for D in
do
```

which would cause your error. To send the exact text to the remote shell, escape any dollar signs that can trigger local expansions and use a format specifier for `printf`.

```
ssh utest@$hostn << EOF

   for D in \$(df -k |grep ora | grep -i \$v_sid | awk '{print \$6}')
   do
       printf '%s\n' "\$(df -h $D |tail -1|awk '{print "FS:", \$6, " usage:", \$5"%"}')"
   done

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to put the condition into [double-brackets](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-script-while-loop-examples/)?

```
while [[ read hostn sid ]]; do
```

Comment: I get the error: ksh[3]: syntax error at line 3 : `hostn' unexpected